# Extracting Manufacture date from Hex in vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, date, bit

Im working with SD card, succesfuly reading SID from ic to vb.net.Problem comes when i need a code for Manufacture date. Datasheet says:

> The manufacturing date is composed of two hexadecimal digits, one is 8
>   bits representing the year(y) and the other is 4 bits representing the
>   month (m). The “m” field [11:8] is the month code. 1 = January. The
>   “y” field [19:12] is the year code. 0 = 2000. As an example, the
>   binary value of the Date field for production date “April 2001” will
>   be:  00000001 0100.

Understing this wasnt hard, the hard part is to create a code which will put DateTime according to hex numbers. For example i recevied 0x00 0xAC [000000000000000010101100] we take only 12bits(first 4 is reserved), it means [000010101100], first 8 bits is a year 0x0A = 10(DEC) = 2010, and last 4 bits its a mounth [1100] = 12(DEC), so it means we have 12.2010 Manufacture date. How to do this kind of manipulation with bits then put result into DateTime? I receive HEX in string representation through serialport.readexisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `BitArray()` to convert the 2 Hex values to their bit representation, in a byte array.
Then, `Math.Pow()` converts the value, using the bits positions, to a decimal representation.
The `new Date()` constructor is used to generate a DateTime object from the values of Year and Month, to then convert to string in the desired format.

Given the two Hex values `0x00` `0xAC`:

```
Dim sHexValue1 As String = "0x00"
Dim sHexValue2 As String = "0xAC"
```

Note that the first byte is set to the value of `0xAC`, the second to `0x00`.

```
'Convert the two "Hex" strings to byte
Dim bytes As Byte() = {
    Convert.ToByte(sHexValue2.Substring(2, 2), 16),
    Convert.ToByte(sHexValue1.Substring(2, 2), 16)
}
'Convert the byte array in array of bits. => True means that the bit is on (1)
Dim bArray As New BitArray(bytes)

Dim month As Integer = 0
Dim year As Integer = 0

'Convert to decimal the value expressed by the first 4 bits
For x As Integer = 0 To 3
    month += If(bArray(x) = True, CType(Math.Pow(2, x), Integer), 0)
Next
'Convert to decimal the value expressed by bits 4-12
For x As Integer = 0 To 7
    year += If(bArray(x + 4) = True, CType(Math.Pow(2, x), Integer), 0)
Next

Dim resultDate = New Date(year + 2000, month, 1).ToString("MM.yyyy")
```

Comment: When working in VB, I'd recommend to use the exponentiation operator rather than `Math.Pow`.  Also, I'd personally prefer to use `CInt` rather than `CType(..., Integer)`.

Comment: @Craig Well, you really can't use the "Hat" in VB.Net, because you have to run the code to see its results, and when you do, (X^y) compiles to Math.Pow(X, y). CInt(n) and CType(n, Integer) compile to the same IL:  `ldc.r8     n.`   `stloc.0`   `ldloc.0`  `call    float64 [mscorlib]System.Math::Round(float64)`    `conv.ovf.i4`  :)

Comment: @Jimi I'd expect `CInt` and `CType(..., Integer)` to compile to the same IL, but I'd personally prefer `CInt` because it's a lot more concise and more immediately obvious what the code does (less human parsing required).  Similarly for the exponentiation operator (and note that VB does allow for overloading the exponentiation operator).